# PHP: Using Ajax to get records from Database and insert HTML

Tags: php, jquery, html, mysql, ajax

I have several records from my database displayed like this in HTML.

```
<?php foreach($adverts_list as $ad) { ?>
  <!--anuncio 1-->
    <div class="card all ad-isotope <?php echo $ad->ad_categorie; ?>">
      <div class="card-body">
        <div class="card-title">
          <div class="card-info">
            <i class="fa fa-tags"></i>
            <p class="card-tag"><?php echo $ad->categorie_name; ?></p>
            <?php if($ad->subCategorie_id != 10) { ?>
              <p class="card-subcat"> <?php echo $ad->subCategorie_display; ?></p>
            <?php } ?>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="new-symbol">
          <p>
            <?php if($ad->ad_nouveau == 1) { 
              echo "nouveau";
            } ?>
          </p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-subtitle">
          <p class="db-title"><?php echo $ad->ad_title; ?></p>
          <p class="db-subtitle"><?php echo $ad->ad_subtitle; ?></p>
        </div>

        <div class="card-readmore">
          <a data-toggle="modal" href="#ad-detail-modal-<?php echo $ad->ad_id; ?>">
            <p class="read-more">voir l'annonce</p>
          </a>    
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

But i wan't to filter it according to a click in a button. I'll have 10 buttons, each corresponding to a category. I wan't to extract the innerHTML from the button, and match it to the records with the same category.
I'm stuck here

```
  //save in variable all elements refering to categories
  var categorias = document.querySelectorAll("a.link");
  //a loop to create event on click of each element
  for(var i = 0; i < categorias.length; i++) {
    categorias[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
      //save innerHTML
      var categoria = this.innerHTML;
      //make ajax call
        $.ajax({
        url: "index.php",
        type: "GET",
        dataType: "html",
        success: function(response) {


          }
        });
    });
  }
```

How can i make the ajax call to search for the records that have the saved category, and display only those?

Comment: the objective is to drop the isotope filtering

Comment: You can use ajax jquery function to make an ajax call. If you search on official documentation or google ypu can find a lot of tutorials

Comment: You can also use this script [https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html](https://isotope.metafizzy.co/layout-modes/masonry.html)

Comment: @Sfili_81 i already use that script. I wan't to replace the isotope filtering with ajax requests

Comment: So take a look on jQuery documentation and write your ajax call

Comment: good tutorial: https://labs.jonsuh.com/jquery-ajax-php-json/